# Hive Date String Validation

Tags: hive, hql, unix-timestamp

I am trying to check if a string is in valid date format of ‘YYYYMMDD’ .

I am using the below technique. But for an invalid date string I am getting a valid date result.

What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT'20019999',CASE WHEN unix_timestamp('20019999','YYYYMMDD')  > 0 THEN  'Good'ELSE 'Bad'END;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you are using the wrong format

```
select  from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())                 as default_format
       ,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'YYYY-MM-DD')    as wrong_format
       ,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'yyyy-MM-dd')    as right_format
;
```

---

```
+----------------------+---------------+---------------+
|    default_format    | wrong_format  | right_format  |
+----------------------+---------------+---------------+
| 2017-10-07 04:13:26  | 2017-10-280   | 2017-10-07    |
+----------------------+---------------+---------------+
```

---

Second, there is no validation on date parts range.
If you increase the day part by 1 it forwards you to the following day.

```
with t as (select stack(7,'27','28','29','30','31','32','33') as dy)
select  t.dy
       ,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(concat('2017-02-',t.dy),'yyyy-MM-dd'),'yyyy-MM-dd') as dt

from    t
;
```

---

```
+-----+-------------+
| dy  |     dt      |
+-----+-------------+
| 27  | 2017-02-27  |
| 28  | 2017-02-28  |
| 29  | 2017-03-01  |
| 30  | 2017-03-02  |
| 31  | 2017-03-03  |
| 32  | 2017-03-04  |
| 33  | 2017-03-05  |
+-----+-------------+
```

If you increase the month part by 1 it forwards you to the following month.

```
with t as (select stack(5,'10','11','12','13','14') as mn)
select  t.mn
       ,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(concat('2017-',t.mn,'-01'),'yyyy-MM-dd'),'yyyy-MM-dd') as dt

from    t
;
```

---

```
+-----+-------------+
| mn  |     dt      |
+-----+-------------+
| 10  | 2017-10-01  |
| 11  | 2017-11-01  |
| 12  | 2017-12-01  |
| 13  | 2018-01-01  |
| 14  | 2018-02-01  |
+-----+-------------+
```

Even with CAST the validation is done only on the parts ranges and not on the date itself.

```
select cast('2010-02-32' as date);
```

---

```
+-------+
|  _c0  |
+-------+
| NULL  |
+-------+
```

---

```
select cast('2010-02-29' as date);
```

---

```
+-------------+
|     _c0     |
+-------------+
| 2010-03-01  |
+-------------+
```

---

**Here is a way to achive you goal:**

```
with t as (select '20019999' as dt)
select  dt  
       ,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dt,'yyyyMMdd'),'yyyyMMdd') as double_converted_dt    

       ,case 
            when from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dt,'yyyyMMdd'),'yyyyMMdd')  = dt 
            then 'Good' 
            else 'Bad' 
        end             as dt_status

from    t
;
```

---

```
+-----------+----------------------+------------+
|    dt     | double_converted_dt  | dt_status  |
+-----------+----------------------+------------+
| 20019999  | 20090607             | Bad        |
+-----------+----------------------+------------+
```

Comment: @jenesaisquoi, great :-)